# load cross domain image in Texture - Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load an image using `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url)` but since image is in a different domain than on which web page is hosted , I am getting below error :

*Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at*

I added `THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous"` before loading texture but then I get below error :

*Image from origin 'cross domain url' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'hosted url' is therefore not allowed access.*

I also tried below code :

```
var url = 'http://www.corsproxy.com/yourdomain/yourfolder/yourimage.png';    
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.crossOrigin = '';
            image.src = url;
            var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
            material.map = texture;
```

but since proxy are blocked on my side , so not able to load cross domain images by this way also , 
Please let me know how can I proceed with loading cross domain images in THREE.js Textures. I am using ver 66 of Three.js..

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is client side language, It won't allow. You have to use server side coding to access cross domain data.

see [java open pdf file when it is being downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221428/java-open-pdf-file-when-it-is-being-downloaded/23472977#23472977)

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-access-to-restricted-uri-denied-solution/